# Oracle Wallet config

Tags: oracle, spring-data

I am trying to configure oracle wallet in my spring app. below is the error:

> Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
>   Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified ]

I put all configuration files(cwallet.sso, ewallet.p12) &  jars() & setup tnsnames.ora
Below is the code.

```
private DriverManagerDataSource getDriverManagerDataSource(final String driver,
                                                           final String url,
                                                           final String username,
                                                           final String password) {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("oracle.net.wallet_location", pathToWallet);
    dataSource.setConnectionProperties(props);

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    //dataSource.setUsername(username);
    //dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Malik,

The example program does not have complete information.

I think In your program if you replace below code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("oracle.net.wallet_location", pathToWallet);
```

with

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "**tnsnames.ora_file_location**");
System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", "**Oracle_Wallet_Location**");
```

It should resolve your issue.

I have setup my oracle wallet by following below steps.

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%\BIN

mkstore -wrl D:\oraclewallet\wallet -create  (Provide wallet password)

mkstore -wrl D:\oraclewallet\wallet -createCredential **Tns_Entry_Name** **Schema_Name** **Password**
```

Entries in %ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\admin\sqlnet.ora

```
WALLET_LOCATION =(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=**Oracle_Wallet_Location**)))

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

Here you should be able to connect to db using sqlplus

```
sqlplus /@**Tns_Entry_Name**
```

Below java run time arguments should be set while running the java program

```
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=**%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN**

-Doracle.net.wallet_location=**Oracle_Wallet_Location**
```

Otherwise we can set during runtime as

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "%ORACLE_HOME%\\NETWORK\\ADMIN");

System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", "Oracle_Wallet_Location");
```

Now for getting db connection you should use the database url as

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@**tns_entry_name**
```

[Sample Program Test Result Oracle Wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Say3M.jpg)

Make sure you have below jars in classpath

- ojdbc6.jar
- oraclepki.jar
- osdt_cert.jar
- osdt_core.jar

Sample code to test

```
package datasourcetest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class DataSourceConnectionExample {
    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@**tns_entry_name**";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "**%ORACLE_HOME%\\NETWORK\\ADMIN**");
        System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", "**Oracle_Wallet_Location**");

        Connection conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 'test' name FROM dual");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer :)

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck I have updated the detailed information